# Skipping first line on a loop

Tags: java, loops, dataset

I want to add data to a dataset to display some values on a graph. On some files, the first line is a description of the columns (like "Timestamp" or something else). I need my code to test if the first line contains integer or float values and if not to skip this line and add data to dataset from 2nd line.

This is my code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listOfLists.size(); i++) {     
    for (int j = 1; j < listOfLists.get(i).size(); j++) {

        if (listOfLists.get(i).get(0).matches("\\d+(?:\\,\\d+)?") || listOfLists.get(i).get(0).matches("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?")) {
          datasetBar.addValue(Float.parseFloat(listOfLists.get(i).get(j).replace(",",".")),columnsLabel[i].getText(), ""+listOfLists.get(0).get(j));    
        } else if(listOfLists.get(i).get(1).matches("\\d+(?:\\,\\d+)?") || listOfLists.get(i).get(1).matches("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?")){
          datasetBar.addValue(Float.parseFloat(listOfLists.get(i).get(j).replace(",",".")),columnsLabel[i].getText(), ""+listOfLists.get(0).get(j));
```

The problem is that I get an error when he's trying to represent String on the plot of the bar chart

List of lists is a list of columns. Each column of the file is added into a list and each list into the **listOfLists**.
I tried to use on the **else if** block: `listOfLists.get(i).remove(0)` but it didn't worked. (in next loops it keeped removing the first line of the remaining list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you start the second iteration with j=1 and not j=0?

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the outer loop, before inner loop:

```
if (i == 0 && listOfLists.get(i).get(0).matches(/\\d+(?:[\\.,]\\d+)?)/) == false) {
    continue; // skip first line
}
```

BTW: You should not call remove method while iterating list because you will get ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfLists.size(); i++) {     
    for (int j = 0; j < listOfLists.get(i).size(); j++) {
        if (j==0){ // Only test if it is a string in position [0]
            boolean isNumber = listOfLists.get(i).get(0).matches("\\d+(?:\\,\\d+)?") || listOfLists.get(i).get(0).matches("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?");
            if (!isNumber) continue; // If it is not a number, skip it
        }

        // Add to database, because it is a number
        datasetBar.addValue(Float.parseFloat(listOfLists.get(i).get(j).replace(",",".")),columnsLabel[i].getText(), ""+listOfLists.get(0).get(j));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help anyone to understand.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ /* i = 0 means position of i is 0 which is 1st line */
   if(i != 0 ){  /* and as our purpose is skipping first line so I will only continue when i is not equal 0 like this we can skip first line in this if block */
     continue;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation